# None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch?

Tags: android, kotlin

This error occurs when i try to add Firebase to my project.
When i add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'` to my `Project build.gradle` there are error in my Fragment on `return binding.root`

```
class PublicationsFragment: Fragment(){

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val binding: FragmentPublicationsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_publications, container, false)

    return binding.root
}
```

}

> None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver
>
> type mismatch: internal val File.root:File defined in kotlin.io

Comment: Are you sure it's because of the google-services? If you remove the dependency the error disappears?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516299/cant-get-root-view-from-data-binding-after-enabling-safe-args-plugin

Comment: @JensV Yes, it disappears

Comment: @SaurabhThorat Thank you.

Comment: @JensV Yes, just renamed layout file